# Make javascript happen in real time

Tags: javascript, dom

I have made a circle from a div with rounded borders. I have made this div draggable using jquery ui. I would like to know how to make it so that the further to the left you drag the div the less opacity it has. Heres a snippet of what i have coded already:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(function() {
    $( "#circle" ).draggable();
  });

  var circ = document.getElementById('circle');
  var num = circ.style.left/1000;



</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="circle"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">circ.style.opacity = num;</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know i can get this to work by putting the circ.style.opacity = num; into a function and calling that function but i was wondering if there was a way for it to just automatically change?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's with the `var circ = document.getElementById('circle');` code there? It won't won't since the element does not exist yet.

Comment: You need to hook into the draggable's callback events. Read up: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events

Comment: @Diodeus Thanks for the feedback. Yeah i looked at that but that would only correspond to the distance the circle was dragged. If it was dragged from left to right and then back, it would not reset to zero like i wanted. Basically , my question is , is there any way to link two values together in javascript so that when one changes eg. the circles position, the other changes as well eg. the opacity?

Comment: @user1976322 A correlation between one value and another? That sounds [oddly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) [familiar...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(computer_science))

Comment: @user1976322: That's exactly what you would do in the callback. Compute the opacity based on on the element's current position. The `drag` callback is executed whenever the element is moved.

Comment: Yes I understand how to compute the opacity based on the current position. But how do I make the opacity change in real time as the user is dragging the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already suggested, simply calculate your opacity in the `drag` callback and set the opacity. The `drag` callback is called continously until the drag stops. This is how the "live" update works.

Example:

```
$('#circle').draggable({
    "drag": function (e, ui) {
        var percentOpacity = someVal; //compute this however you like
        $(this).css('opacity', percentOpacity);
    }
});
```

**Working Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gzA8w/

In the working demo, I am simply calculating the opacity as a function of how many pixels the element is from the right edge of the document. The further left you go, the more transparent it gets.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realise that the callback function was executed in realtime.

Comment: I'm gonna go read up on callbacks now..Thanks a million, I would upvote you but it says I need more rep points :/ Cheers anyway.

Comment: I have enough points to upvote you now so there you go...4 years too late but better than never :)